# Route website to subdomain in digitalocean

Tags: dns, digital-ocean

I'm trying to route a subdomain media.xyz.com to another droplet in digialocean. My main domain xyz.com points to a different server correctly.

My zone record looks like this

```
@   IN A    107.170.51.xx
www CNAME   @
media   IN A    107.170.52.xx
```

However this does not work and the sub domain (media.xyz.com) redirects to my main webserver.

I've read the digital ocean tutorial on this and I think I've set it up correctly. I've also looked over questions on SO and the general advice is to create a new A record.

Could anyone tell me if this approach should work..? Or is my understanding on how this should work incorrect..?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you need to add record for your subdomain like what explained here:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-and-test-dns-subdomains-with-digitalocean-s-dns-panel

so simply in your DO control panel under your domain, do the following:

Add A record --> write down your subdomain end up with dot like this: **media.xyz.com.**

and your droplet IP in the 2nd field next to that: **107.170.51.xx**

try that and see if it works or not!!

Comment: thanks the issue was I didn't know it would take so long for the changes to be updated.

Comment: this directs to the root folder of my droplet IP

If I want to redirect login.xyz.com to 107.170.51.xx/login

How can i achieve this?

Comment: what does it mean?? can you re-explain again!! do you want to redirect or is this solution doing the redirect?

Comment: If i want to redirect the same to a folder inside my website what i have to do?